Understanding what I might have done wrong with this question
This is in regards to my recent question: Is there a rigorous way to formalize $\operatorname{Aut}(\zeta)$?. I must admit I was very surprised at the voting here with no feedback at all.
However to put myself in the shoes of other mathematicians seeing these concepts for the first time, I can sort of see that they might find my post strange and confusing although I'm not sure exactly what I've done so wrong to get five downvotes.
This is clearly research level material to me (but perhaps maybe it's not to the mathematicians on this site). I realize with all the AI hoopla going on people might suspect it is AI generated, but that is not the case at all.

So please help me understand where I've gone wrong here. All I care about is improving. Is it the notation, the structure of the argument, something else?

Thank you so much!

It's a giant wall of text, and it is hard to assign any precise meaning to the question at the end of it.  I tried to figure out what you were trying to ask several times, and I still have no idea at all.

(and I think other people agree with me since there are 3 votes to close for the reason "needs more details or clarity")

Okay I will go for less text and more clarity I think. Thanks for the feedback

It's highly unclear what $\zeta$ in the title is. I had to scroll down a page to see the definition of $\zeta^n$, after it was mentioned mysteriously in the first paragraph, and with merely a skim read, I still have no idea even what kind of mathematical object $\zeta$ on its own is supposed to be.

The first sentence of your post is "A short summary of the post: each $p\in\zeta^n$ is an $\mathcal F$-completion and the same, simultaneous $\Gamma$-action on each point, yields an automorphism of $\zeta^n$." I could find no definition of $\zeta^n$, no definition of $\Gamma$, and the sentence defining $\mathcal F$-completion is excessively vague ("obtained by extending foliations to accumulate at specific vertices in the boundary"), in addition it requires to understand your definition of "block" which I'm having hard time to decipher.
